# how to read only the first digit and avoid writing this value into the binary file

Tags: arrays, c, file, binary, structure

Need to write a program in C
There is an array of structures written in a .txt file, the structure includes: the starting point of the route, the end point of the route and the route number (30 characters are allocated for the beginning and end of the route). It is necessary to write these data into a binary file, ordering them by route number, then the user enters the route number into the program, and information about this route (start and end points of the route) is output from the binary file.

Teacher's comment - "Only information about a specific route, and not the entire array of structures, should be loaded into RAM"

P.S. I wrote the code for the previous task, where the user himself enters all the information into an array of structures, it may come in handy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
 
#define N 8
 
struct MARSH
{
    char startOfRoute[30];
    char finalOfRoute[30];
    unsigned int routeNumber;
};
 
void findRoute(unsigned int, struct MARSH*, int*, bool*);
void sortRoutes(struct MARSH*);
 
int main()
{
    int index;
    bool exist;
    unsigned int routeChoice;
    struct MARSH listOfRoutes[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter start point of route: ");
        fgets(listOfRoutes[i].startOfRoute, 31, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter final point of route: ");
        fgets(listOfRoutes[i].finalOfRoute, 31, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter number of route: ");
        scanf("%u", &listOfRoutes[i].routeNumber); 
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    sortRoutes(listOfRoutes);
    printf("\nEnter the route number you need information about: ");
    scanf("%u", &routeChoice);
    findRoute(routeChoice, listOfRoutes, &index, &exist);
    if (!exist)
    {
        printf("\nThere is no such route number.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nStarting point of the route: %s", listOfRoutes[index].startOfRoute);
        printf("The final destination of the route: %s\n", listOfRoutes[index].finalOfRoute);
    }
    return 0;
}
 
void sortRoutes(struct MARSH* listOfRoutes)
{
    struct MARSH temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if(listOfRoutes[j].routeNumber>listOfRoutes[i].routeNumber)
            {
                temp = listOfRoutes[j];
                listOfRoutes[j]=listOfRoutes[i];
                listOfRoutes[i]=temp;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
 
void findRoute(unsigned int routeChoice, struct MARSH* listOfRoutes, int *index, bool *exist)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(routeChoice == listOfRoutes[i].routeNumber)
        {
            *exist = true;
            *index = i;
        }
    } 
}
```

I can't figure out how to read only the first digit (the number of records in the file) and avoid writing this value into the binary file.

Comment: Is the number of records stored in the first line of the file by itself? In that case, all you have to do is to read that line using `fgets` and convert it to a number using `strtol`. You could also use `fscanf` with the `%d` specifier, but beware that this will leave the newline character on the stream.

Comment: To me, your question lacks clarity, and while posting unrelated code shows you at least have done some work it's confusing as it's only tangential to the question.  I am guessing you trying to read a digit of `routeNumber`.  What is digit?  As it's a binary file you need to read at least a byte.  A 2-base digit would be a bit.  Which one?  Do you want a base-10 digit?  Which digit?  In that case you want to read an `unsigned int` and extract the relevant value from it.  As you have fixed sized format, you know you can seek `i * sizeof(struct routeNumber) + 60` to find the i'th `routeNumber`.

Comment: If your input file is sorted you can do binary search, if you need to sort the file, it's not a lot of fun do record at a time (i.e. selection sort, appending the sorting value to a new file).